# cordova iOS custom splash screen

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

i added a splash screen to my iOS project per https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html

i didn't like it and removed the entries from config.xml and deleted the image files.

i rebuilt my project and ... my splash screen still shows.

in platform/ios//Resources/splash all the png files i created (and deleted) are still there.

if i delete it, the build fails with errors saying the splash directory is missing.

how do i get rid of these files?  where are the coming from?  how on earth do i get rid of the splash screen?

Comment: Are you rebuilding your project in xcode? To apply changes to the project template, you run `cordova prepare`. Then build your project.

Comment: i've been doing 'cordova build ios' from the command line and then running it in Xcode's simulator so its getting built twice.  i have done 'cordova prepare ios' prior to 'cordova build ios' and its not done any good - platform/ios/Resournces/splash still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this, albeit accidentally.

i had to upgrade to a new version of a plugin and as part of that process i did:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

afterwards, the splash screen was gone